# VueRouter and Express.js

Tags: express, vue-router

when i use the **express.js** to buid the server and `xxxxx:3000`(my root url).
in this state i use then **vue-router** to `xxxxx:3000/foo` (**anther child path**) is work.

---

the ***question*** is when i **refresh** then page width url(`xxxxx:3000/foo`),it show me then 404(Cannot GET /foo1).
 i try to  **redirect** when i refresh the page with the url has **/foo**?

Comment: try to add router.get("/:paramName") than you will be able to access /foo or /foo1. you can access foo and foo1 as a url params.

Comment: i wanto rewrite like the function .htaccess in apache